# Objective C, Convert html to NSAttributeString and disable the hyperlinks

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm using

```
    [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[HTMLText                         
    dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:options 
    documentAttributes:NULL error:NULL];
```

to convert HTML string to AttributeString and use it in a textView, however, I don't want the hyperlinks in the text to be clickable in the textView,  is there any way I can remove the hyperlinks behind the texts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A link in an `NS(Mutable)AttributedString` is represented by an attribute, `NSAccessibilityLinkTextAttribute`. You can remove individual attributes. In outline:

- Make a mutable copy of your attributed string
- Use `enumerateAttribute:inRange:options:usingBlock:` to locate all the links
- In the block passed to the above use `removeAttribute:range:` to remove the link

Read Apple's [`NSAtributedString` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1412461-enumerateattribute?language=objc).
HTH